# Mobile Theme not working in Ipad magento 2

Tags: iphone, ipad, magento2, user-agent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWtNz.png)

We've two themes in our project one for desktop and another for mobile.

Mobile Theme not working in Ipad magento 2.

/iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|BB10|16.1 Mobile|604.1/i

above code is in my search string.

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

Thanks,

/iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|BB10|16.1 Mobile|604.1/i

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.